# How functionally compose functions ( f(g(h))) in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reduce

So... in Underscore there is a function called "compose" 
http://underscorejs.org/#compose
`Returns the composition of a list of functions, where each function consumes the return value of the function that follows. In math terms, composing the functions f(), g(), and h() produces f(g(h())).`

And even without Underscore you can achieve the same effect by using reduce:

```js
var mappers = [
    function add_100(v) {
        return v + 100;
    },
    function mul_2(v) {
        return v * 2;
    }
];

console.log(
    [1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {
        // we transform n by passing it to the all mappers
        // so result will be: mul_2( add_100(n) )
        return mappers.reduce(function (currentResult, mapper) {
            return mapper(currentResult);
        }, n /* initial value for pipeline */ )
    })
); // ---> [202, 204, 206] 

// because: 
// (1 + 100) * 2 = 202
// (2 + 100) * 2 = 204
// (3 + 100) * 2 = 206
```

But this approach is good when functions `add_100` or `mul_2` are synchronous and returns value immediately. Because I need asynchronous functions I started using RxJS.

And off course, there is a `reduce` operator in RxJS but it seems to work synchronously, like in VanillaJS.

```js
var Rx = require('rx')
var mappers = Rx.Observable.from([
    function add_100(v) {
        return v + 100; // works in Rx because it's synchronous 
    },
    function mul_2(v) {
        return v * 2; // works in Rx because it's synchronous
    }
]);

Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).map(function (n) {
    // we transform n by passing it to the all mappers
    // so result will be: mul_2( add_100(n) )
    return mappers.reduce(function (currentResult, mapper) {
        return mapper(currentResult);
    }, n /* initial value for pipeline */ )
}).mergeAll().subscribe(console.log)
// 202
// 204
// 206
```

When functions add_100, and mul_2 are asynchronous e.g. returns Observable instead of immediate value it doesn't work anymore.

So... I actually make some solution to walk around this but it looks ugly and not very clear:

```js
var Rx = require('rx')
var mappers = Rx.Observable.from([
    function add_100(v) {
        return Rx.Observable.create(
            o => {
                // line below concerns me most:
                v.subscribe( value => o.onNext(value + 100) );
            }
        );

        return Rx.Observable.from(v + 100);
    },
    function mul_2(v) {
        return Rx.Observable.create(
            o => {
                v.subscribe( value => o.onNext(value * 2) )
            }
        );
    }
]);

Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).map(function (n) {
    return mappers.reduce(function (currentResult, mapper) {
        return mapper(currentResult);
    }, Rx.Observable.from([n]) /* initial value for pipeline */ ).mergeAll();
}).mergeAll().subscribe(console.log)
```

note that I'm using arrow notations from ES6. In ES5 it would look even uglier.

What I really wanted is something like this:

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3])
.map(Rx.compose(mappers))  // my imaginary Rx.compose util like in Underscore
.mergeAll()
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Or at least some nicer that hacky solution I've figure out. Off course I could make my own utility for that, but this is not a problem. I wonder if there is maybe some nice Rx-way solution for these kinds of problems? Rx is high level library so I thought maybe I won't rediscover wheel but ask what people more experienced in Rx/reactive approach would say.

Or maybe inb4 I'll hear "your solution is elegant, nothing wrong with that". Maybe. I just feel mental overhead when I look at this code.

Comment: Take a look here https://jsbin.com/kavagi/1/edit?js,console maybe it will be helpful for you

Comment: You're looking for [`composeP`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#composeP) :-)

Comment: composeP works only with promises

Comment: and I'm not sure that adding dependency of whole Ramda library to perform simple operation is good. But conceptually yes, I thought just about something like that. Or something like in xgrommx's snippet.

Comment: Although I've already figured simple solution for my problem (which costs me only adding 3 additional lines of code), look below :)

Comment: Yeah! In general you can take a look here http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/mappingr_rxjs_from_different_libraries/async/index.html#asynccompose (Very similar to our solution)

Comment: Have you tried `transducers` with `Observable` sequences. Check out [https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/transducers.md](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/transducers.md)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out very simple solution:

```js
var Rx = require('rx');
var mappers = [ 
    function add_100(v) {
        return Rx.Observable.return(v + 100);
    },
    function mul_2(v) {
        return Rx.Observable.return(v * 2);
    }
];

mappers.reduce( // magic happens here
    (o, mapper) => o.flatMap(mapper), // and exactly here.  
    Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3]) // initial observable we want to transform
).subscribe(console.log);

// 202
// 204
// 206
```

It's functionally equivalent to this:

```js
// ... (initializing code the same like above)

Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3])
  .flatMap(mappers[0])
  .flatMap(mappers[1])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Only made in more flexible way (number of mappers is unknown).